# How to change wsl 2 kali linux non-UNICODE terminal character encoding to UNICODE terminal character?

Tags: kali-linux, unicode, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to use Airodump-ng in WSL 2 KALI LINUX and they give me the the following warninig:

Warning: Detected you are using a non-UNICODE terminal character encoding

when I type $locale charmap, I get that I am using ->ANSI_X3.4-1968

then how to change ANSI_X3.4-1968 to UTF-8 so to have a UNICODE terminal?
tell me how to get a UNICODE terminal in wsl 2 kali linux?

Comment: Well what terminal are you using? Does it support Unicode?

Answer (score 0):

Typically, the character map is part of the locale settings that you're using.  If you don't have any locale settings set, they default to `C` or `POSIX`, which use ASCII (in this case, written as `ANSI_X3.4-1968`).  This warning occurs when the locale's character set is not `UTF-8`.

On most modern Linux systems, you can simply use the `C.UTF-8` locale, which works just like the `C` locale, except that it uses UTF-8.  Typically, you can do this by setting the environment variable `LANG` to `C.UTF-8`, usually in your shell configuration, and then restarting your shell (e.g., with `exec bash` or `exec zsh`).  You can also change this for the current shell by doing `export LANG=C.UTF-8`.

You may also wish to use a locale which reflects the language and territory you're actually located in, or one whose language you care for.  For example, you could choose `en_US.UTF-8`, `es_MX.UTF-8`, or `fr_CH.UTF-8` as you see fit.  Note that on some systems, you need to compile locales before you can use them, whereas `C.UTF-8` is typically available without needing to do this on systems where it's available at all.

Note that you can also change this by setting `LC_ALL`, but that overrides all other settings, whereas `LANG` is the fallback default.  As a consequence, it's better to use `LANG` so you can customize individual settings (e.g., `LC_TIME`) as you see fit.

It might also be the case that the locale was set to `C` by the terminal emulator because it simply doesn't support UTF-8, but that's not the case for Microsoft Terminal (the default WSL2 terminal emulator) or virtually every other modern terminal emulator, which do indeed support UTF-8.